# Flutter Linuix & Mac OS & Web: The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition

Tags: linux, flutter, macos, dart, scrollcontroller

I used Flutter Linuix:

I had a few basic children that need to scroll a little bit so I needed a listview to enable scrolling and got this exception a smple code like this:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Text(
      'data',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 215),
    ),
    Text(
      'data',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 215),
    ),
    Text(
      'data',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 215),
    ),
  ],
)
```

The following assertion was thrown while notifying status listeners for AnimationController:
The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is simple just add controllor to the listveiw like this:

```
ListView(
      controller: ScrollController(),
  children: [
    Text(
      'data',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 215),
    ),
    Text(
      'data',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 215),
    ),
    Text(
      'data',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 215),
    ),
  ],
)
```

source:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85456

Comment: I had this error on Flutter web and this fix worked for me as well

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this error you could wrap your widget tree in a ScrollConfiguration:

```
ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
          child: ListView()
```